# Windows 7 folder sharing API

Tags: winapi, windows-7, uac

I wonder if it's possible to programmaticaly share folders in Windows 7 while running in restricted logon session:

1) NetShareAdd returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.
2) Command line net share says the same.
3) But explorer has no problems creating new shares without invoking UAC. How does it do that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a non-administrator session?

Comment: No, it's administrator, but not real administrator (UAC)

Comment: Are you sure that Explorer is actually creating the share?  For example, if I share a subdirectory of something that's already shared, I don't see the shield; however,if I try to share something that's not already shared, the shield icon is displayed.

Comment: Yes, there is the shield icon on the button "Advanced Sharing", but I don't get any prompts from UAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UAC in windows 7 is less strict than it was in Vista. Windows 7 regards Explorer as a trusted application so it will silently create the share without a UAC prompt (you can change this behavior in the Control Panel).

Your application isn't a trusted one (OK, you trust it, but the operating system does not). Probably you also don't explicitly demand administrator rights in your application. In that case Windows 7 treats your program as unprivileged and refuses access, that why the error message.

A solution could be adding a manifest to your program requesting an ExecutingLevel of requireAdministratior. See for example  [Demand UAC elevation for an application by adding a manifest](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx). But then your **whole** application runs as administrator. There are some more granular solutions.

Comment: Thanks for explanation (trusted application part)

Comment: What are the more granular approaches? I'd like to avoid escalating my app to run as admin, but I need to share folders (for instance).